# Best practices when implementing Relational Models who need constraining logical cardinality across several entities

Tags: sql, database, uml, relational-database, entity-relationship

There are N cities.

Each city disposes M different types of souvenir fridge magnets

Then there are Y travelers. Every traveler collects Z magnets, but always a single one per city at most.
Two different travelers could buy same city magnet.

```
 N city 1 <--> M magnets Z <--> Y traveler
```

I'd like to be appointed about the best way to enforce that a traveler can have Z magnets if and only if each magnet corresponds to a single city, in a relational fashion with keys or better normalization, or simply know the best practice strategy for it.

Comment: What is your guess (at least 1 example please)?

Comment: I thought of either do a circular constraint chain (like traveler foreign key referencing to city again) or using a trigger. But I feel like they are dirty solutions

Comment: Another solution would be to model the UML association class `city 1 <- bought -> 1 traveler` and implement it as `unique index` with `city.id` and `traveler.id` as the keys. But it is **also dirty** solution as it will throw a constraint violation exception from the database layer. Something that decent application should not event attempt to do

Answer (score 1):

**UML**

1.Magnet * <--> 1 City

2.Bought - association class beetwen City and Traveler

3.Bought * <--> 1 Magnet

4.OCL constraint: context Bought inv:city=magnet.city

**DataBase**

*City*

1.idCity (PK)

*Traveler*

1.idTraveler (PK)

*Magnet*

1.idCity (PK, FK)

2.idMagnet (PK)

*Bought*

1.idCity (PK, FK1)

2.idMagnet (FK1)

3.idTraveler (PK, FK2)

Comment: please give some explanation, I don't understand what you're saing.